# ARP poisioning and proxy

Tags: proxy, arp

Suppose i am on  a network. iam using my facebook in https mode using a proxy server (which i got from hidemyass.com

Now suppose some person in my lan performs arp poisioning and I am the victim computer so i know he would be able to see my whole lot of traffic... but will he be able to see my facebook traffic also.. i know the password part would be encrypted but what about the url that i visit. and how to protect myself from it. i googled like protection from arp poisining  but they provide me solutions on a network level..what about a solution at user level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how effectivly he is able to perform a MitM attack against you. There is only real what against ARP spoofing on a standard home network. Some networks provide a way for managed switches and notes to lock a MAC to an IP and report the attack when it occures however this is uncommon for most home networks.

As far as reading your encrypted traffic is concerned due to the way Certificate Authorties perform there checking on both the server and client side it would be unlikely to see an attack actually work unless the attacker had the server's private key or redirect your browser to a private key your browser will accept. What you will most likely see is a miss matched key exception in which the key provided by the attacker will not be automatically accepted by your browser.

Comment: what about the url's that i visit..they aren't encrypted( i suppose)..and i don't want people to see what site am i visiting....

and if i use proxy server(as in this case)
what would the be seeing 
10.x.x.x <proxy server address>
or would they be seeing 
10.x.x.x facebook.com while doing arp poisioning

Comment: Hidemyass.com creates the proxy by using a system of a frame inside of a frame for their basic service. If you enable SSL encryption no one except for the people at hidemyass.com should be able to read your traffic. This however brings up a new problem. If you are looking for a proxy you can trust I would suggest setting up an SSH server on your own local network. [Look into SOCKS5 proxying] This would give you the advantage of creating a secure connection from any remote system(your desktop) to the server through the proxy connection. This doesn't eliminate the ARP spoofing problem however.

Answer (score 1):

No, Attacker won't be able to see the traffic.
The only thing attacker will see is that your traffic is going towards a particular proxy server.
That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no general protection in networks that use a dynamic configuration. if you wish to have protection it has to be supported by the hardware (switch) where the arp poisoning attack is recognized and the systems are shielded.

If an attacker has access to your data stream he has the control over it.

Known tools for arp mitm attack are [cain & abel](http://www.oxid.it/cain.html) and [AyCarrumba](http://web.archive.org/web/20130330145650/https://www.megapanzer.com/2012/06/07/fishing-passwords-with-aycarrumba/)